# Password generation and validation from database

Tags: sql, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to make a method of password validation for an assignment that wants me to only allow passwords containing 'NT' followed by the last 6 digits of an existing student ID (eg. NT123456). The user will enter their last name and password on the first page, and I will run it through a query. From there if the record count is greater than 0, they were redirect to a portal, otherwise they will be told it was incorrect, but that isn't as important right now.

The form I'm using is here:

```
<cfform name="form" action="PortalPage.cfm">
<cfinput type="Text" name="password" maxlength="8">
<cfinput type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</cfform>
```

Which sends the form info to here:

```
<cfquery name="qry1" datasource="grantme">
SELECT 'NT' + RIGHT(StudentID, 6) AS Passwords, Lname
FROM Classmates
WHERE Passwords = form.password;
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="qry1">
#qry1.RecordCount#
</cfoutput>
```

But I'm getting the following error report:

```
 Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.

The error occurred in G:\InetPub2\wwwroot\student\A00507999\PortalPage.cfm: line 9

7 : 
8 : <body>
9 : <cfquery name="qry1" datasource="grantme">
10 : SELECT 'NT' + RIGHT(StudentID, 6) AS Passwords, Lname
11 : FROM Classmates

VENDORERRORCODE       -3010
SQLSTATE      07002
SQL        SELECT 'NT' + RIGHT(StudentID, 6) AS Passwords, Lname FROM Classmates WHERE Passwords = form.password;
DATASOURCE    grantme
```

What can I do too fix this? I can't seem to get the format right, but the logic seems to be there.

Comment: It looks you are retrieving two values from the DB but providing only one to receive them.

Comment: the problem doesn't stem from that, since I can display values if I remove the WHERE clause, but I need the WHERE clause to do what I need to do.

Comment: I think my wording was not clear... You are selecting `Passwords, Lname` into... what? Don't you need to specify the variables that need to receive these TWO values?

Comment: It will receive the last name in the row where the alias column 'passwords' matches the password entered in the form by the user. However as I said, nothing is happening with that which would cause the error. The error is happening in the WHERE clause, despite what the error report says.

Comment: Ok. If you are 100%... Good luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the query working.  The comparison is between a varchar column and a string.  Strings should be delimited with single quotes.  The pound signs are necessary too.

```
<cfquery name="qry1" datasource="grantme">
SELECT 'NT' + RIGHT(StudentID, 6) AS Passwords, Lname
FROM Classmates
WHERE Passwords = '#form.password#';
</cfquery>
```

To protect against SQL injection attacks this is the best way to write the query.

```
<cfquery name="qry1" datasource="grantme">
SELECT 'NT' + RIGHT(StudentID, 6) AS Passwords, Lname
FROM Classmates
WHERE Passwords = <cfqueryparam value="#form.password#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">;
</cfquery>
```